What does "within ten Days (Sundays excepted)" — the veto period — mean in Art. I, § 7, Cl. 2 of the US Constitution?

Every Bill which shall have passed the House of Representatives and the Senate, shall, before it become a Law, be presented to the President of the United States; If he approve he shall sign it, but if not he shall return it, with his Objections to that House in which it shall have originated, who shall enter the Objections at large on their Journal, and proceed to reconsider it. If after such Reconsideration two thirds of that House shall agree to pass the Bill, it shall be sent, together with the Objections, to the other House, by which it shall likewise be reconsidered, and if approved by two thirds of that House, it shall become a Law. But in all such Cases the Votes of both Houses shall be determined by yeas and Nays, and the Names of the Persons voting for and against the Bill shall be entered on the Journal of each House respectively. If any Bill shall not be returned by the President within ten Days (Sundays excepted) after it shall have been presented to him, the Same shall be a Law, in like Manner as if he had signed it, unless the Congress by their Adjournment prevent its Return, in which Case it shall not be a Law.
U.S. Constitution Article I, Section 7, Clause 2


If Sundays don't count, and this is in excess of a week long, such that a Sunday must fall in this span of time (sometimes twice), does this mean the 10 days can actually span 11-12 calendar days?

           1 
12 345678 90 <- Eligible days
FSUMTWHFSUMT 

         111 
123456789012 <- Calendar days 
FSUMTWHFSUMT
  ^      ^
  |      |
  |      +- No returning on Sunday
  +- No returning on Sunday


Or does it only mean no returning bills on Sunday? So you actually run outa time to return in 9 calendar days if the bill was presented on a Friday.

         1
1234567890  
FSUMTWHFSU
  ^     ^^
  |     ||
  |     |+- No returning on Sunday
  |     +- Last day you can return
  +- No returning on Sunday


Where does the signing come into play?

@littleadv when signing it into law vs returning it, which I thought had the same timeframe.

"If any Bill shall not be returned by the President within ten Days (Sundays excepted) after it shall have been presented to him" - nothing about signing. Only returning.

@littleadv better now?

As a complete side-note, you may find useful a convention used by some to use "MTWRFSU" as a sequence of letters to uniquely represent, each with a single letter, each of the 7 days of the week.  As far as I know, this isn't an official standard anywhere, but I remember a community college using it, which may or may not have influenced Apple using it in their pmset command.  (See also: mtwrfsu in a Wikipedia talk page.)

@lindes ok done.

@littleadv If he signs it, returning it is moot. BTW, "return" means what we now call "veto".

@Barmar so could a bill presented on Wednesday be saved from pocket veto if signed on the 2nd Sunday?

@candied_orange Not that I can see. Sunday only matters when determining the time limit for explicit veto. He can sign on any day.

@Barmar oh that's funny. So the law says, do as you like with your day off. But don't you mess with ours.

@candied_orange It's giving POTUS more time to veto, since Sundays don't count against the 10-day limit. There's no limit on the time to sign, unless the bill is passed within 10 days before Congress adjourns.

This clause has been interpreted to simply not count Sundays towards the 10-day time limit within which the President must return a bill to Congress in order to effect a veto.
See e.g. House Practice, Chapter 57, "Veto of Bills":

The 10-day period given the President under the Constitution in
which to approve or reject a bill begins at midnight at the close of
the day on which the bill is presented to him. The day on which the bill is
presented to the President is not counted in the computation, and
Sundays also are excluded.

Drafting history
On August 6, 1787, the draft version of this clause read "within seven days."
On August 15, 1787, this was amended to the current language, without debate or comment.

When that clause was enacted, it meant "10 working days".  Saturday was a working day like Monday and Friday.

I'm taking this to mean interpretation 1 is correct. If it's not let me know why.

@david this has also always been my understanding, but I have also long wondered why they chose "ten."

@phoog: Ten stinks of arbitrariness. I don't think the founders put much thought into it at all - they probably just wanted a smallish number that would be long enough for the President to make an informed choice about whether to veto the law. Then they
(presumably) worried that Congress might strategically hold votes later in the week in order to interfere with the President's deliberations, so they exempted Sundays.
